# Fullcalendar -> Change color selected event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar and I can't change the background of the events of a selected date.
The other days when you click are marked with red, but events no. I think it is by the CSS but I do not know how to modify it to work well.

My code: http://jsfiddle.net/y33wb52n/

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fecha_seleccionada;
    var tempVar = "";

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        lang: "es",

        selectable: true,
        select: function(a, b) {
            fecha_seleccionada = a.format();
            //alert(fecha_seleccionada);
            var input_fecha = document.getElementById("input_fecha");
            input_fecha.value = fecha_seleccionada;
        },

        //defaultDate: '2015-02-12',
        editable: false,
        eventLimit: false, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [
                {
                    title: 'Evento',
                    width: '0',
                    start: '2015-09-17'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Evento',
                    width: '0',
                    start: '2015-09-19'
                }
        ],


        dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
            // change the day's background color just for fun
            if (tempVar == "")
            {
                $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
                tempVar = this;
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
                $(tempVar).css('background-color', '#f6f6f6');
                tempVar = this;
            }
        }


    });
});
```

CSS

```
.fc-event-skin {
margin: -20px auto 0px auto; /* spacing between events and edges */
padding: 30px 0px;
border-radius: 0px !important;
```

}

HTML

```
<div id='calendar' style='margin:3em 0;font-size:13px'></div>
```

Any help?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Are you trying to change the background color of all events when they're loaded, or events when they're clicked?

Comment: I'm trying to change the background of the days I click. But the days with events are not marked with red.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that's because if you click an event you're not clicking on the day. I had a play with the example you provided, and it's true if you click on an event it doesn't change colour, but you can actually click on the day *behind* the event which does change its colour.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKDiR.png

So, when you're clicking an event, the dayClick event isn't firing, the eventClick event is firing.

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/

Not sure how you're supposed to get the day that's behind the event from inside that callback though.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this to your css:

```
.fc-highlight {
    background-color:red;
}
```

This works when day is clicked, so you should have this in your fullcalendar jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
           $('#calendarID').fullCalendar({

           dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
                // some code
                $('#calendarID').fullCalendar('select', date);

           },
...
```